# How to restrict user from modifying data in mysql data base?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We need to deploy application(developed by Java) WAR file in client place which make use of MySql 5.0. But we would like to restrict the client (the application owner, not the webpage visitor) from modifying any data in the database. Is there any way to protect data. The client can make use of the application but they should not be able to change any value in database. How to do that?

Comment: @BalusC:Thanks for editing and making it understandable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible; if you deploy the application at the client, he will have the credentials and will be able to log into the MySQL database and pretent he is the application. And thus he can make any change to the database that your application can.

The only way to solve this securely is to make a tier between the client and your MySQL database, and make sure that you control this so that it is only possible to make 'legal' changes.

Comment: And what if the credentials are for a user without modifying rights? Or only certain stored procedures are used?

Comment: What has to done between client and MySQL database. Pl mention clearly whether it is possible or not!

Comment: If the credentials are for a user without modifying rights, the application (and stored procedures) cannot makes changes either. This is contrary to the question.

Comment: @wump: a WAR file signifies a **web** application. So I bet that the client doesn't run at the same machine as the server. The only wall is the Java webapp code and the control is fully at the server side (at the developer). So unless the code is prone to SQL injections, there should be absolutely no problem and MySQL user/roles has absolutely no influence on this. It's all how you control the access to the webapp itself (by HTTP) and how the webapp is programmed.

Comment: It UI will work like what we progrmmed. But what i am asking is at the back side of DB by directly changing the value of records by logging into the DB

Comment: @BalusC: Assume that the WAR file is going to run at local host at client side so DB will reside in that system alone. Same system acting as client & server.

Comment: @Paul: you should have been more clear on that :/ Then the answer of @wump is correct. If the DB runs at the client, you cannot restrict the control in any way. It's like as attempting to restrict the control all of the DB's and servers at **my** laptop right here. Think logically.

Comment: @BalusC:Now i am clear that if i deploy every thing in client machine i can't do it any way. It can be controlled if it is in our hand. Thanks for all people participation and make myself clear. Thanking you once again :)

Answer (score 5):

Manage **Role/User permissions**

Create an sql user (you should already have one), which will have only **SELECT** permission. So it would be something like

```
GRANT SELECT ON db_base.* TO db_user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd';
```

http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/788/HOWTO:+GRANT+privileges+in+MySQL

http://blog.wl0.org/2010/01/managing-mysql-grants/

http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/grant.html

Check links below for further reading

**FOR MySQL**

[Best Practice for Designing User Roles and Permission System?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333620/best-practice-for-designing-user-roles-and-permission-system)

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3311731/An-introduction-to-MySQL-permissions.htm

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/MySQL-User-Account-Management/

[Can't set permissions on MySQL user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796619/cant-set-permissions-on-mysql-user)

http://www.aquafold.com/d7/docs/BD5C99E4-3B55-C812-8318-6338A9A89ED9.html

**FOR SQL Server**.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3311731/An-introduction-to-MySQL-permissions.htm

http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Adm/SQL70Roles.htm

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/object_permission_scripts_p1.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1061781.html

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2246271/Managing-Users-Permissions-on-SQL-Server.htm

Comment: @hgulyan: I am using MySql 5.0. but your links pointing to sql-server. any suggestion for this.

Comment: @Paul, If you consider, that I've answered to your question, accept it:)

Comment: @hgulyan, Ok fine.Thanks for your support through answers :) Have a great day

Answer (score 2):

Just write the code accordingly so that the user doesn't have any chance to modify the database? I.e. the code doesn't execute any `INSERT` or `UPDATE` and/or controls the access based on a login/role.

I honestly really don't forsee any problems here, or the code must be prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).

**Update**: The above answer is actually irrelevant since the question is clarified. Turning into Community Wiki.